# Getting Dynamically passing the Parameter Array in Function

Tags: vb.net

I have some problems with this code. Could you help me to find a solution about this program ?

```
Module Module1
Function AddElements(ParamArray arr As Integer()) As Integer
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each i In arr
        sum += i
    Next i
    Return sum
End Function
Sub Main()
    Dim sum As Integer
    Dim k As Integer()
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Array Value")
    n = Console.ReadLine()
    For j = 1 To n
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of:")

        k(j) = Console.ReadLine()

    Next
    sum = AddElements(k(j))
    sum = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.WriteLine("The sum is: {0}", sum)


    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: It looks like you are passing only a single element and not the entire array to your AddElements function.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to initialize k() with the size it is supposed to have.
2. As JRSofty said you are currently passing a single int and not an array to the function.
3. What is the point of `sum = Console.ReadLine()`? You calculate the sum but then overwrite the value with input from the console.

Corrected code

```
Module Module1
Function AddElements(ParamArray arr As Integer()) As Integer
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each i In arr
        sum += i
    Next i
    Return sum
End Function
Sub Main()
    Dim sum As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Array Value")
    n = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim k(n) As Integer '1
    For j = 1 To n
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the value of:")           
        k(j) = Console.ReadLine()  
    Next
    sum = AddElements(k) '2
    'sum = Console.ReadLine() '3

    Console.WriteLine("The sum is: {0}", sum)


    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```